# Two django generic Class Based Views into the same template

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have been researching on how to render a single template using two class based views and I have not found any material addressing the same. For instance the home.html template with a functionality of creating a new post and at the same time listing all the posts in the database. How do I implement such functionality.

```
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
model = Post
template_name = 'home.html'
fields = ['title', 'body']

class BlogListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'home.html'
```

Comment: basically, you want to add the post and than show the added post in the same template.

Comment: exactly. @ngawang15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class-based views are great in theory, but sometimes they just make things overly complicated. You can use this function-base-view which is easy.

```
def list_and_create(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
   form = FormNameYouCreated(request.POST or None)

   if form.is_valid():
     form.save()

# notice this comes after saving the form to pick up new objects
post = Post.objects.all()
return render(request, 'home.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks alot @ngawang13 for your response.

Comment: So, is it working for you. any problem working on it?

Comment: with the function based view, it is working very well. Only that I thought maybe there is an easier way of doing it in generic class based views since they usually look simplified. I think I will have to stick to function based views in my project. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: ohhh ok..! For a beginner its better to stick to FBV as you will get a good idea on how all the codes are working.